# Adding comments to my website via AJAX in laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I have a website with recipes that users can comment on any recipe. right now when a user submits a comment, the whole page is reloading, and i wanted to make it via AJAX for better UX. My code as of now is this:

In My route/web.php

```
Route::post('comments/{post_id}', 'CommentsController@store');
```

In My CommentsController

```
public function store(Request $request, $post_id)
{
    $this->validate($request, array(
        'name'=>'required|max:32',
        'email'=>'required|email|max:255',
        'comment'=>'required|min:5|max:1000'));

    $comment = new Comment;
    $post=Post::find($post_id);
    $comment->name=$request->name;
    $comment->email=$request->email;
    $comment->comment=$request->comment;
    $comment->post()->associate($post);
    $comment->save();
    Session::flash('success', 'The Comment Was Added!');
    return redirect()->route('slug',[$post->slug]);
}
```

The above code is working. Now, when i try and make it like this, it does not work.

My Ajax:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
        $(".postbutton").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: '{{route('comments.store',$post->id)}}',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {_token: CSRF_TOKEN, name:$(".name").val(),
                email:$(".email").val(),comment:$(".comment").val()},
                dataType: 'JSON',
                success: function (data) {
                    $(".msg").append(data.comment);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

And in my controller i have changed it to this:
In My CommentsController

```
public function store(Request $request, $post_id)
{
    $this->validate($request, $response=array(
        'name'=>'required|max:32',
        'email'=>'required|email|max:255',
        'comment'=>'required|min:5|max:1000'));

    $comment = new Comment;
    $post=Post::find($post_id);
    $comment->name=$request->name;
    $comment->email=$request->email;
    $comment->comment=$request->comment;
    $comment->post()->associate($post);
    $comment->save();
    Session::flash('success', 'The Comment Was Added!');
    response()->json($response);
}
```

I get a 404 response, but I have checked the routes (all the same as before, not its just with ajax), and all is good. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you give us a 404 error response? What does it say?

Comment: Is that ajax call producing the error or the page itself?

Comment: Before the ajax it was just fine, now... not that much as you can see. @RossWilson

Comment: What?!? That doesn't answer my question. Also, if that is your actual `Route` then `route('...')` shouldn't work as your not actually defining a name for the route. If you run `php artisan route:list` can you confirm that there is a name for the uri?

Comment: It is a resource route, ao everything is with a name for that route. like comments.index etc'